# Should we allow embedding videos in questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers

The question hit me when I saw [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/what-is-our-location-relative-to-the-big-bang) which I know two brilliant youtube answers for it. I already posted my answer, but it would be much nicer if I could embed and include the videos in my answer, so there would be no need to open another link to get the whole answer.

Looking around in the mother meta, I've found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers); and in an answer there is pointed that embedding videos has been enabled in some sites like [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/) and [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). Can we discuss the pros and cons of allowing videos on Physics SE, and make a decision 
about it?

Comment: Related: [How do deal with questions based on videos?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4918/how-to-deal-with-questions-based-on-videos)

Answer (score 5):

The thing that makes me very reluctant to pursue this is that people seems to have no sense for the amount of time they are asking readers (well, viewers) to invest when they link to videos.

Sometimes they seem to be saying

> Oh, yeah. Just watch this [47 minute] clip and I'm sure I recall it being in there somewhere.

More aware users, of course post that you can find the answer around [time hash], which is helpful, but I rarely want to follow such links anyway.

Finally, I'm sure there are people who would try to take this as license to post what are in effect link-only answer. Or worse, link-only *questions*. Heck, we have some of that already.